# How to arrange 'sizes' attribute for reps.imgs in a mobile-first context

Tags: image, responsive-design, srcset

I'm setting up images for a responsive web design and am adopting the recently-formalised responsive images syntax. I'm not using all aspects, just the srcset and sizes parts. Roughly-speaking, my markup is as follows:

```
<img src="/image.jpg" alt="my alt text"
    srcset="
        /image-sm.jpg 320w,
        /image-md.jpg 480w,
        /image-lg.jpg 600w,
        /image-xl.jpg 742w"
    sizes="
        (min-width: 992px) 742px,
        (min-width: 768px) 582px,
        (min-width: 600px) 441px,
        (min-width: 480px) 599px,
        (min-width: 321px) 479px,
        320px"
>
```

My design is built in a mobile-first way. So my question is this:

Does the order of the media queries make any difference to which image gets picked by the browser?

As you can see I have them going from largest breakpoint to smallest, because the default size is small and all the syntax examples I've seen put the default size at the end. But this is in contrast to my main CSS (compiled via SASS) which also uses min-width media queries, where I (correctly) have the smallest breakpoints coming first.

Should I have the smaller breakpoints first in this markup, also? Or does it make no difference within an image markup context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order does matter. In CSS later rules do override prior rules, if they have the same specificity. This might yield to the result, that later CSS is overriding prior ones.

In context of resp image the first size value is taken, which matches the media condition. This might result in the opposite ordering effect.

This means if you use min-width, your sizes list only makes sense, if it goes from higher min condition values to lower values (Your example).

If you want reverse your list (from lower to higher), you need to use max-width conditions instead to express the same CSS values thing.

At the end: Do it how you want, but keeping min-width condition and just reverse the list, won't work.

---

At the end, with sizes there is not a mobile first or desktop first approach, only a simple universal approach.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. My original uncertainty stemmed from the fact that the media queries were appearing as part of HTML markup rather than strictly within the context of CSS, so I wasn't sure if all the same rules a applied. In fact, Sizes apparently uses 'Media conditions' rather than true media queries, compounding the uncertainty. But, as you say, it appears that they work the same way. Jason Grigsby recently verified it well in this post: http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-part-5-sizes/ (scroll down to the subheading ‘How does the browser select the correct sizes value?’. Handy.